# Using Gson to serialize ArrayList of objects with non-primitive values?

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson, sharedpreferences

So I have this class

```
public class Place {

    ArrayList<Stop> stops;
    String name;
    Location location;

    public Place(String name, Location location){
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void addStop(Stop stop){
        this.stops.add(stop);
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name+ " : " +location.toString();
    }
}
```

That I use for an Android project. Each Place object has a Location object (from Google Play Services) and the app has a ArrayList *items* arraylist that stores user input data. I'm using Gson to serialize that ArrayList and save it to SharedPrefs, but when I restore the data, all the parameters from the Location object come out *null*. Here's my code:

```
//If user has defined places, load them from storage
mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("user_places", "");
Type placeListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Place>>(){}.getType();
if(json.length() > 0) items = gson.fromJson(json, placeListType);
else  items = new ArrayList<Place>();

...

//Saves user data for future use
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(items);
prefsEditor.putString("user_places", json);
prefsEditor.apply();
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that the original Location object is restored properly?

Comment: Does it happen as well for 1, 2 or 1000 places and/or stops?

Comment: Could you show `JSON` which you receive after serialisation?

Comment: I ended up changing `Place`'s structure. Instead of having a `Location` object, it just stores the longitude/latitude coordinates of the initial `Location` object, and the app reconstructs it upon deserialization. When I tested the `JSON` String returned by GSON, I noticed that only one of the parameters from the `Location` object was being serialized (The time at which the `Location` was recorded). So it likely was an issue with serializing, and not deserializing

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, it's maybe because you are loading and saving your Json string from 2 different activities.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

getPreferences() method will work only if you're accessing your values in the same activity.

If you want to save your values to SharedPreferences in activity A, and get them later in activity B, try using this instead:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(items);
prefsEditor.putString("user_places", json);
prefsEditor.apply();
```

And then access them like this:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("user_places", "");
```

Comment: It's all in the same activity actually... I used getActivity() instead of 'this' because this is happening in a fragment. I'm not really having issues with saving or retrieving the data to and from sharedprefs. My issue is that upon deserializing, the parameters from the Location object nested inside the Place object (itself nested into the ArrayList I'm saving) are null.

Comment: @Dat8StringGuy well, that's strange, I'd recommend you to display your Location object value inside logcat, so you'll know that maybe you're passing null as an argument into the constructor. Also maybe consider to create a field String locationJson, convert location to json in the constructor (if previously you checked that Location object you passed into the constructor is not null), yea that sounds not so good, but I dont have any other thoughts